# Remove space in between mandatory * and label in SAPUI5

Tags: css, sapui5

We have space between the * and title Payment Method.

I am using following code

```
new sap.ui.commons.form.FormElement({
    label: "Payment Method",
    fields: [
        new sap.ui.commons.ComboBox("PaymentMethod", { 
            items : [
                new sap.ui.core.ListItem("PaymentMethod1", { text: "Wire" }),
                new sap.ui.core.ListItem("PaymentMethod2", { text: "ACH" })
            ],
            required:true,
        })
    ],
    layoutData: new sap.ui.commons.layout.ResponsiveFlowLayoutData({
        linebreak: true, 
        margin: true
    })
})
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Voting to close since all `sap.ui.commons.*` controls are deprecated as of UI5 v1.38 making the question less likely to help future readers. Additionally, it promotes anti-patterns such as introducing custom CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the CSS as:

```css
.sapUiGridLabel > .sapUiLbl.sapUiLblReq:before {
  color: #006CA7;
  content: "*";
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right: 0px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```